# Rails 3. How to create a custom PUT action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rake

I'm trying to create a custom action for a Update My Profile Page. It can't be the regular users#edit or users#update action because only Admins can use that page.

So this is what I have in routes.rb (side question: how can I make the link become mydomain.com/users/update_profile instead of mydomain.com/update_profile?

```
get 'update_profile/:id' => "users#update_profile", :as => 'update_profile'
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => update_profile_path(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => "form", :locals => {:f => f} %>
<% end %>
```

users_controller.rb

```
def update_profile
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
    end
  end
end
```

When I submit the form I get this: **Routing Error No route matches [PUT] "/update_profile/1"**

I understand the error because according to the output of `rake routes` the update_profile action is GET.

So I need to change it to PUT, but I don't know how. How can I setup a custom PUT action in routes.rb?

Comment: Isn't it as simple as changing `get 'update_profile/:id'` to `put 'update_profile/:id'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add it as a member of your `users` resource

```
resources :users do
  member do
    put :update_profile
  end
end
```

This way it will still be part of your users resource and the route will be automatically generated and be accessible in your form through something like `update_profile_user_path(@user)`

Comment: I get this error `Couldn't find User without an ID` with this URL `http://localhost:3000/users/1/update_profile`. I also tried `put 'update_profile/:id'` and it tells me that I'm missing an action.